# Android - How to pass interface to AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to figure out how to create an AsyncTask that runs my php API code in the background then alerts my MainActivity once it completes. I've been reading tutorials and trying things for hours now and I'm just frustrated at this point as I can't find anywhere that answers my question.

I create the AsyncTask and it runs successfully and I can log the returned information from my API in the onPostExecute but I cannot figure out how to alert the MainActivity that the task was completed. I do not know what to pass into the creation of the APICall. Every tutorial I read shows that the AsyncTask constructor takes the interface as an argument as shown in my code below, but how do you pass an interface as an argument?

**MainActivity.java** *(implements OnTaskCompleted)*

```
myButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
            APICall api = new APICall( ???What do I put here?? );
            api.execute("users");
         }});
....

@Override
public void onTaskCompleted() {
    Log.v("Play","Main Activity ON Task completed!");
```

**OnTaskCompleted.java**

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
public void onTaskCompleted();
}
```

**APICall.java** *(extends AsyncTask)*

```
public APICall(OnTaskCompleted listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

....

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject j)
{
    listener.onTaskCompleted();
}
```

Comment: It has been a long time since this discussion! but I have the same problem. if you pass a context/activity when you do It has been a long time since this discussion! but I have the same problem. When you do in the constructor of the asynctask this.listener = listener, you must have an illegal cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the reference of your listener to the APICall class:

```
APICall api = new APICall(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! I was searching so long for this. You made my night now I can sleep in peace :) Thank you!

Comment: you better put this listener in WeakReference in AsyncTask to avoid leaks and accessing dead UI instances.

Answer (score 1):

Simple you can use anonymous interface instance like this.

```
myButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                APICall api = new APICall(new OnTaskCompleted() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTaskCompleted() {

                    }
                });
                api.execute("users");
            }});
```

OR you can Implement interface at class level like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainActivity.OnTaskCompleted {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        myButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                APICall api = new APICall(MainActivity.this);
                api.execute("users");
            }});

    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted() {

        // Do your code on task complete
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> APICall api = new APICall( ???What do I put here?? );
>
> What do I put here??

The one that implements your listener in this case your `MainActivity`

```
APICall api = new APICall(MainActivity.this);
```